# How to make Java ServiceActivator visible in JUnit Test?

Tags: java, junit, spring-integration

How to make Java ServiceActivator visible in JUnit Test?

I have started writing a test which imports some spring integration xmls via some Java Config files (ie, files set in the @ContextConfiguration). One of these xml files references a channel called **pollerErrorChannel** this is the input-channel to a ServiceActivator declared in a Java Class. When the test cranks up I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sftpInboundAdapterBusiness': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1fe8d51b' of type [org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata] while setting bean property 'pollerMetadata'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1fe8d51b': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#324dcd31' of type [org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler] while setting bean property 'errorHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#324dcd31': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pollerErrorChannel' while setting bean property 'defaultErrorChannel'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'pollerErrorChannel' available

Below in my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class, 
    SFTPSampleReceiver.class,
    SampleIngestBusinessConfig.class, 
    SampleIngestConfig.class, 
    SessionFactoryConfig.class},
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations={"/application.yml"})
public class BusinessSampleRecieverTests {


    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
```

}

Segment from **sample-ingest-business.xml** which specifies **pollerErrorChannel** as a channel

```
   <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInboundAdapterBusiness"
        channel="sftpInboundBusiness"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="${sftp.localdirectory}/business-local"
        filter="businessCompositeFilter"
        remote-file-separator="/"
        remote-directory="${sftp.directory}/business-sftp">
    <int:poller cron="${sftp.cron}"  max-messages-per-poll="1" error-channel="pollerErrorChannel"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Here is The Java Class which specifies **pollerErrorChannel** as the InputChannel to a @ServiceActivator

```
@Slf4j
@MessageEndpoint
@Component
public class SFTPSampleReceiver {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pollerErrorChannel", outputChannel = "errorUploadChannel")

    public Message<String> processInvalidSample(GenericMessage errorMessage) {

        String error = ((Exception) errorMessage.getPayload()).getCause().toString();
        String fileName = ((MessagingException) errorMessage.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders()
            .get("file_name").toString();
        String directory = ((MessagingException) errorMessage.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders()
            .get("sample_type").toString() + "-sftp";
        String shortFileName = fileName.replace(".xml", "");
        String errorFile = shortFileName + "_error.txt";

        log.debug(fileName + " Was invalid and rejected.");

        final Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(error).setHeader("error_file_name",
            errorFile).setHeader("file_name", fileName).setHeader("short_file_name",
            shortFileName).setHeader("directory", directory).build();

        return message;
    }


}
```

thanks

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? Try adding `@EnableIntegration` to one of your `@Configuration` classes or `<int:annotation-config/>` to your XML.

Comment: The <int:annotation-config /> worked, thanks. Im using version 4.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garys comment about adding `< int:annotation-config/>` to your `XML` worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare that `pollerErrorChannel` bean.

With just a `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pollerErrorChannel"` it will be already to late to have that channel auto-created. The `<poller>` is parsed and populated as a bean a bit earlier.

We might review the `PollerParser` to use `MessagePublishingErrorHandler.setDefaultErrorChannelName()` isntead of `errorHandler.addPropertyReference("defaultErrorChannel", errorChannel);` to let to resolve the channel late on demand.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter!